# Regex stopping before commas

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to write a parser in arcsecond, but it keeps cutting off the strings right before the commas.

I want to turn a custom data format into JSON, and the way it's currently structured, each line up until the first space is the key and everything after that is the value.

The problem is that my code stops reading the line when it hits a comma. I've checked it in a regex checker and it works fine there.

Relevant code:

```
const key = regex(/^[\t]?[A-Za-z]{1,20}[0-9]?/);
const alphaSpacesPunctuation = regex(/^[A-Za-z ,.:;?!'"]{3,300}/);
const value = choice([alphaUnderscore, alphaSpacesPunctuation, alphaOnly, pstring, integer, decimal, expo, triplet, quotes, textureName, regionName]);
const kvParser = choice([ sequenceOf([key, regex(/^[ ]{1,2}/), value]), empty, openBracket, closedBracket ]);
```

The line it's looking at is

```
About For over twenty years, she has lived in Canada.
```

It's separating "About" from the rest like it should, but stops right after "years". It does the same thing for a few other value strings, too. All the other punctuation marks get picked up as normal.

What might be causing this? Am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: I can't begin t find out what this arcsecond parser does, but my best guess is that the value is matching `years` instead of `years,` because of the order in which you've listed them. If you want to match including the comma then order the value choices in most inclusive to most restrictive. Meaning try swapping `alphaUnderscore` and `alphaSpacesPunctuation` for start. Also, don't forget to put left and right single and double-quotes in that regex.

Comment: `alphaSpacesPunctuation`  is the only one that allows commas, though.

Comment: Yes, so that would make it most inclusive, meaning it should get higher priority.